# I'm trying to open a dialog when the view is tapped

Tags: android

I am trying to open a dialog when the view is tapped. 
MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DialogInterface alertDialog1;
    ...
    public  void cangrats(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Your Choice");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                builder.setCancelable(true);
            }});
        alertDialog1 = builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

, maze class:

```
public class maze extends View {
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

    public maze(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            mainActivity.cangrats();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

, error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.blah.blah.myapplication, PID: 4435
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:149)
                      at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:114)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:294)
                      at com.blah.blah.myapplication.MainActivity.cangrats(MainActivity.java:17)
                      at com.blah.blah.myapplication.maze.onTouchEvent(maze.java:25)
                      at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9943)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:411)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
                      at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:373)
                      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10163)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3995)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4052)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6210)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6184)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6145)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6313)
                      at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: you can not create a Object of activity class,You have to pass the Object of Context.

Comment: Define Context context and put this `context=this`

Answer (score 0):

Do these modifications:

In you `maze.java`

```
  public class maze extends View {
  MainActivity mainActivity; // do not instantiate mainActivity object
public maze(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if(mainActivity==null)
         return true;
        mainActivity.cangrats();
    }

    return true;
}
 // Create a method to pass MainActivity reference to maze
 public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity)
 {
           this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
 }
}
```

In MainActivity's `onCreate` method call `setMainActivity` method

```
mazeObj.setMainActivity(this);
```

Comment: What is mazeOBj?

Comment: mazeOBj is object of maze class

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with this code, First of all you **don't** create activities like that:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

this code doesn't create a usable activity, the activity won't have a context since is not attached to application process, the activity won't get started, it is just a empty container!

If you want to create and start an activity you must ask the `ActivityManager` using **intent** like this:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
```

Secondly `builder.create()` return `AlertDialog`, don't cast it to `DialogInterface`!

Lastly `builder.setCancelable(true)` won't work! When dialog is shown the builder job is over if you want to dismiss the dialog you don't have to do anything since the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` dismiss the dialog by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can you use static method for this and show your dialog
like this and also create your variable like this

 AlertDialog alertDialog1

 public static void cangrats(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Your Choice");
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            builder.setCancelable(true);
        }});
    alertDialog1 = builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```

and you use in your view class like this MainActivity.cangrats();